# How to increase scalability the method that output each file while switching multiple many conditions?

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp.js

I have a common style (`common.scss`) and a text direction (RTL, LTR) option file (`option-document-direction-rtl.scss`, `option-document-direction-ltr.scss`). And by switching the reading of these files, the css file with RTL / LTR changed is output by method like gulp.js.

**_common.scss**

```
body {
  max-width: 1120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: $direction;
}
```

**_option-document-direction-rtl.scss**

```
$direction: right;
```

**_option-document-direction-ltr.scss**

```
$direction: left;
```

**style.scss**

```
@import "option-document-direction-rtl";
// switch to @import "option-document-direction-rtl";

@import "common.scss"
```

And I can get below *two css files same time* by some method (actually these scss files style be more complex):

**rtl-style.css**

```
body {
  max-width: 1120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}
```

**ltr-style.css**

```
body {
  max-width: 1120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
```

---

#### Main subject

So, I have to switched these style condition different from text direction. For example, screen size without media queries. In this case, I think need a new options SCSS file, such as `_computer.scss` and `_smartphone.scss`. Here, I had a question.

The number of configuration files with new conditions may increase in the future. In the current method, in short, the css file to be output is changed depending on which of the "configuration files that describe the settings used in each condition" is read.

I'm afraid that my configuration files will grow and become more difficult to manage. What tools and mechanisms on SCSS can be used to increase the scalability of many configuration files?

I considered a method of dynamically changing the output file according to the argument at the time of build, but I have not been able to determine whether this is a way to improve scalability.